# Synchronize using an external computer/ account

Tags: sharepoint-online, office

I have 2 different accounts / computers in the company.
The admin account has access to all local network drives and all sharepoint pages.
Here we work with Office 365 Online.
The other (secondary) account / computer only has access to the local network drives. Here we only work with the normal microsoft office.

Now I use the secondary PC to run various Excel tools, which are automatically updated and saved every day.
That The latest version of the tools is always available on the network drive.
Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to access Sharepoint with this account.
Now I would also like to publish this data on a sharepoint.
Is there a way to synchronize this local network drive or the corresponding folder with an admin account to SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps, to synchronize local file share with SharePoint online :

1. Select parts of your file share to sync with Office 365
2. Define your local file system as data source for Office 365 replication
3. Define a SharePoint library in Office 365 as data destination for your file system
4. Setup field mapping for file system metadata
5. Access your local files via Office 365 from everywhere

For details steps, please refer below :

[HOW TO SYNC A LOCAL FILE SERVER WITH OFFICE 365, SHAREPOINT ONLINE OR ONEDRIVE FOR BUSINESS?](https://www.layer2solutions.com/support/cloud-connector-faqs/file-system-sync-with-office-365)